# How to insert date values into table

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, oracle10g, date-formatting

How can I insert into table with different input using /   ,with **date datatype**?

```
insert into run(id,name,dob)values(&id,'&name',[what should I write here?]);
```

I'm using  oracle 10g.

Comment: Could you post some samples of inputs you desire to insert, for more clarification?

Comment: id    name              dob
1      abc          19.12.2008
2      def           20.12.2009

Answer (score 65):

Since `dob` is `DATE` data type, you need to convert the *literal* to `DATE` using `TO_DATE` and the proper format model. The syntax is:

```
TO_DATE('<date_literal>', '<format_model>')
```

For example,

```
SQL> CREATE TABLE t(dob DATE);

Table created.

SQL> INSERT INTO t(dob) VALUES(TO_DATE('17/12/2015', 'DD/MM/YYYY'));

1 row created.

SQL> COMMIT;

Commit complete.

SQL> SELECT * FROM t;

DOB
----------
17/12/2015
```

A `DATE` data type contains both date and time elements. If you are not concerned about the time portion, then you could also use the ANSI Date literal which uses a fixed format `'YYYY-MM-DD'` and is NLS independent.

For example,

```
SQL> INSERT INTO t(dob) VALUES(DATE '2015-12-17');

1 row created.
```

Answer (score 14):

date must be insert with two apostrophes'
As example if the date is 2018/10/20. It can insert from these query

Query -

```
insert into run(id,name,dob)values(&id,'&name','2018-10-20')
```

Comment: No, that's incorrect. In Oracle `'2018-10-20'` is a string, not a date. You must explicitly convert the string into date using `TO_DATE` with appropriate format mask or use `ANSI date literal` which uses fixed format `DATE 'YYYY-MM-DD'`.

Answer (score 4):

let suppose we create a table Transactions using SQl server management studio

```
txn_id int,

txn_type_id varchar(200),

Account_id int,

Amount int,

tDate date

);
```

**with *date* datatype we can insert values in simple format: `'yyyy-mm-dd'`**

```
INSERT INTO transactions (txn_id,txn_type_id,Account_id,Amount,tDate)
VALUES (978, 'DBT', 103, 100, '2004-01-22');
```

Moreover we can have differet time formats like

```
DATE - format YYYY-MM-DD
DATETIME - format: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS
SMALLDATETIME - format: YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS
```

Answer (score 1):

> insert into run(id,name,dob)values(&id,'&name',[**what should I write
>   here?**]);

```
insert into run(id,name,dob)values(&id,'&name',TO_DATE('&dob','YYYY-MM-DD'));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the "timestamp" data type where it just needs "dd-mm-yyyy"

Like:

```
insert into emp values('12-12-2012');
```

considering there is just one column in the table...
You can adjust the insertion values according to your table.

Answer (score 0):

I simply wrote an embedded SQL program to write a new record with date fields.
It was by far best and shortest without any errors I was able to reach my requirement.

```js
w_dob = %char(%date(*date));      
exec sql insert into Tablename (ID_Number     , 
                             AmendmentNo   , 
                             OverrideDate  , 
                             Operator      , 
                             Text_ID       , 
                             Policy_Company, 
                             Policy_Number , 
                             Override      , 
                             CREATE_USER   ) 
                values ( '801010',    
                            1,            
                           :w_dob,      
                           'MYUSER',     
                            ' ',         
                            '01',        
                            '6535435023150', 
                            '1',         
                            'myuser');
```

Answer (score -1):

To insert the current date you can just use this **GETDATE()** function.

`insert into run(id,name,dob) values(&id,'&name',GETDATE());`

you can also use **CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()** function to insert current date and time.

Comment: This answer is for MS SQL. At first I didn't notice the tag of the question.